# VBA - Catch all errors and return the descriptions. Is it possible?

Tags: vba, excel

The question is the following. Is it possible to have errors in code in multiple lines, use the `on error resume next` and at the end return the description of all errors. Something like this:

```
Public Sub CatchErrors()

    On Error Resume Next

    Err.Raise 1009, Description:="Custom Error 01"
    Err.Raise 1010, Description:="Custom Error 02"
    Err.Raise 1011, Description:="Custom Error 03"

    Debug.Print Err.Description

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

I want all the descriptions, not only the last one. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CatchErrors()
    Dim errStrng As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Err.Raise 1009, Description:="Custom Error 01"
    Err.Raise 1010, Description:="Custom Error 02"
    Err.Raise 1011, Description:="Custom Error 03"

    On Error GoTo 0

    Debug.Print errStrng
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    errStrng = errStrng & Err.Description & vbCrLf
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup. Did not know that the resume next there would continue. Thanks! :)

Comment: you are welcome. You may then want to accept the answer ..:-)

Comment: Yup, I will do it once SO allows me to. There is about 10 minutes pause, before asking the question, that does not allow me.